# Create a variable which is only a certain portion of a string variable in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a dataset which has a variable which has urls as its observations. I am trying to create another variable which would list the type of domain for the observation in the "url" variable (`.com`, `.org`, `.co.uk` etc.)

I could split the "url" variable by parsing using "."

`split url, p(.)`

but that would not definitively give me the domain name.

The problem arises due to the high variance in the type of "url"s For. eg.

- while `www.google.com` would be split into 3 variables, `http://www.nih.nlm.gov` would be split into 4
- similarly while `www.yahoo.com` is split into 3, `https://www.movies.yahoo.co.au` would be split into 5.

How can i write the following formula in stata to create the "domain type" variable from the "url" variable

> - if the part after the last "." in the "url" variable has ≥ 3 characters (.com/.edu/.org/.gov or .info) then use this as domain type
>
> > - if the part after the last "." in the "url" variable has < 3 characters ( .uk/.au/.tv etc.) **AND** the part before the last "." has ≤ 2 characters (.co ), then use the part after the penultimate "." as domain type (i.e. .co.uk)
> >
> > > - if the value after the last "." in the "url" variable has < 3 characters ( .us domains) **AND** the part before the last "." has > 2 characters, then use the part after the last "." as domain type (e.g freeshootinggames.us)

Also, is there another way of doing this ?

I am working in Stata 13.1 on Windows 8 Pro x64

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reversing strings is a useful trick in problems like this. Try something like this:

```
gen rev_url = reverse(url)
split rev_url, parse(.) gen(domain_)
replace domain_1 = reverse(domain_1)
replace domain_2 = reverse(domain_2)
replace domain_1 = domain_2 + "." + domain_1 if length(domain_2)<=2 & length(domain1)<3
rename domain_1 domain
drop domain_* rev_url
```